# Can I prevent Babel from traversing code inserted by a plugin?

Tags: babeljs

I'm building a plugin that inserts `enterFunction()` in front of every existing function call by calling `path.insertBefore`. So my code is transformed from:

```
myFunction();
```

To:

```
enterFunction();
myFunction();
```

The problem is that when I insert the node Babel once again traverses the inserted node. Here's the logging output:

> 'CallExpression', 'myFunction'
>   'CallExpression', 'enterFunction'

How can I prevent Babel from entering the `enterFunction` call expression and its children?

This is the code I'm currently using for my Babel plugin:

```
function(babel) {
    return {
        visitor: {
            CallExpression: function(path) {
                console.log("CallExpression", path.node.callee.name)
                if (path.node.ignore) {
                    return;
                }
                path.node.ignore = true

                var enterCall = babel.types.callExpression(
                    babel.types.identifier("enterFunction"), []
                )
                enterCall.ignore = true;
                path.insertBefore(enterCall)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere, the information about to-be-traversed paths needs to be stored. The question is only how. How about a closure? `f = function () { var x = 0; return function () { if (x > 0) return; do_meaningful_things(); x++ } };`

Comment: @meisterluk What I'm wondering is, how can I communicate that to Babel? insertBefore is triggering the new traversal.

Comment: Sorry, I should have understood your sample code better before commenting. Now, the best answer I was able to find is https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4956 Maybe path.skip() works? http://astexplorer.net/#/efhJqnJv5a/1

Comment: @meisterluk Yes, skip() and skipKeys is what I was looking for! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Done - glad to be of any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Babel Handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-stopping-traversal) mentions the following section:

> If your plugin needs to not run in a certain situation, the simpliest thing to do is to write an early return.
>
> ```
> BinaryExpression(path) {
>   if (path.node.operator !== '**') return;
> }
> ```
>
> If you are doing a sub-traversal in a top level path, you can use 2 provided API methods:
>
> path.skip() skips traversing the children of the current path. path.stop() stops traversal entirely.
>
> ```
> outerPath.traverse({
>   Function(innerPath) {
>     innerPath.skip(); // if checking the children is irrelevant
>   },
>   ReferencedIdentifier(innerPath, state) {
>     state.iife = true;
>     innerPath.stop(); // if you want to save some state and then stop traversal, or deopt
>   }
> });
> ```

In short, use `path.skip()` to skip traversing the children of the current path.
One application of this method is illustrated in [this snippet using Visitors, CallExpression and skip()](http://astexplorer.net/#/efhJqnJv5a/1):

```
export default function (babel) {
  const { types: t } = babel;

  return {
    name: "ast-transform", // not required
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(path) {
        path.replaceWith(t.blockStatement([
          t.expressionStatement(t.yieldExpression(path.node))
        ]));
        path.skip();
      }
    }
  };
}
```